# Python - how to handle TypeError elegantly?

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, split, typeerror

Here is an extract from my code :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[1]
    providers = (AlexaTrafficRank(), GooglePageRank(),)

    print((url))
    for p in providers:
        print("%s:%d" % (p.__class__.__name__, p.get_rank(url)))
```

The full code is available here (though it shouldn't all be necessary) : [LINK](http://pastebin.com/PWH8z2nV)

When I call my function in terminal, I pass in a URL as a parameter to this function. For most URLs it will work perfectly, eg :

```
C:\Users\Simon\PC\Test>python GetAlexRanking.py http://www.test.es
http://www.test.es
AlexaTrafficRank:17817109
GooglePageRank:2
```

However, when I call the function with some URLs, I get the following error :

```
C:\Users\Simon\PC\Test>python GetAlexRanking.py http://www.estamos.es
http://www.estamos.es
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetAlexRanking.py", line 193, in <module>
    print("%s:%d" % (p.__class__.__name__, p.get_rank(url)))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

How can I handle this elegantly? The behaviour I would like would be if either of the `AlexaTrafficRank() or GooglePageRank()` methods fail, then I would like a '?' returned rather than  a number. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Handling value errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080983/python-handling-value-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the `p.get_rank(url)` value first, then test:

```
for p in providers:
    rank = p.get_rank(url)
    if rank is not None:
        print("%s:%d" % (p.__class__.__name__, rank))
```

or, since the rank is just a integer, you can use boolean logic and `%s`:

```
for p in providers:
    print("%s:%s" % (p.__class__.__name__, p.get_rank(url) or '?'))
```